# Views not being inflated in Multiview Recycler View Adapter

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, adapter

Implementing a `MultiView` Recycler View Adapter in Kotlin. On the basis of `viewType` I inflate different layouts in `onCreateView`. In `onBindViewHolder`, I set up layout items data but problem is that ids' of views in that item are not being accessed, and getting a `NullPullException`.

I debugged, and found that the switch case and conditions are working fine, but only problem is with the layouts whose views are not inflated. Here is my code for the Adapter:

```
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): 
           RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
           context = parent.context
           return when (viewType) {
                        Constants.PATTERN_TEXTFIELD -> {
                                  TextFieldViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
                    .inflate(R.layout.ques_pattern_inputfield, parent, false))}
               
                               

                       Constants.PATTERN_RADIOBUTTONGROUP -> {
                                  RadioGroupViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
                    .inflate(R.layout.ques_pattern_radiobuttongroup, parent, false)
            )
        }

        else ->{
            TextFieldViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
                    .inflate(R.layout.ques_pattern_inputfield, parent, false))}
    }
}
}


override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, @SuppressLint("RecyclerView") position: Int) {
    var model = list[position]
    model.apply {

        when(holder) {

            is RadioGroupViewHolder -> {

                holder.itemView.let{

                    it.tvQuestion.text = question

              }
            }

             is TextFieldViewHolder -> {

                holder.itemView.let{

                    it.tilInputField.hint = question

              }
            }
          }
        }
      }


 override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
    return list[position].viewType
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return list.size
}

class TextFieldViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view)

class RadioGroupViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view)
```

`NullPointerException` I am getting is attempt to invoke a virtual method on Null object in this line:  `it.tilInputField.text = question`. Where tilInputField is the id of the `TextInputLayout` in the `R.layout.ques_pattern_inputfield` , and this layout is fine.

Comment: Do you use `synthetic` to get view? If so, check if you import the correct layout.xml

Answer (score 0):

Please make these changes and check

```
 (holder as TextFieldViewHolder).tilInputField.text = question
```